# Apache poi write method wont write to blank Excel sheet

Tags: android, excel

---

***Method write wont write to blank excel sheet. Please look at end of code. The function writeToExcel is called by a button. Everything else works fine but the xlwb.write method.***

```
fun writeToExcel(view: View) {
               var myInput:InputStream *// initialize asset manager*
               var assetManager :AssetManager = applicationContext.getAssets() *//  open excel file name as
   myexcelsheet.xls*
               myInput = assetManager.open("workbook.xls") // Create a POI File System object
               var myFileSystem :POIFSFileSystem = POIFSFileSystem(myInput) *// Create a workbook using the File System*
               var xlwb: HSSFWorkbook  = HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem) *// Get the first sheet from workbook*
                val xlWs = xlwb.createSheet("name")
               *//Row index specifies the row in the worksheet (starting at 0):*
               val rowNumber =0            //Cell index specifies the column within the chosen row (starting at 0):
               val columnNumber = 0
               *//Write text value to cell located at ROW_NUMBER / COLUMN_NUMBER:*
               val xlRow = xlWs.createRow(rowNumber)
               val xlCol = xlRow.createCell(columnNumber)
               xlCol.setCellValue("Chercher Tech")
               val filename = ("assets\\workbook.xls")
               val fos = openFileOutput(filename, MODE_PRIVATE)
               xlwb.write(fos) ***// Problem is here it does not write***
               fos.flush()
               fos.close()
               xlwb.close()
}
```

---

Comment: openFileOutput only takes a file name. You cannot specify a directory too.

Comment: Thanks for you input blackapps. I made the change but it still not writing to excel sheet. Got any ideas?

Comment: I see no change.

Comment: Sorry to ask blackapps but what do you mean when you say you see no change? Program is still not writing to blank excel sheet? Could you help?

Comment: I saw no change in your code. Thats all. And now i forgot.